# Ajax function refreshing when using 'fileElementId' attribute for uploading file

Tags: jquery, ajax

My Ajax function is refreshing when i using **'fileElementId'** attribute for uploading the file. Picture is saving to the database with the help of **'fileElementId'** attribute but it destropying the purpose of file upload through ajax. Any help would be appreciated:

### This is my ajax function.

```
<script>
var frm = $('.wrefresh');

frm.submit(function (ev)
{

    ev.preventDefault();

    var postdata = $(this).serialize();
    var path = $(this).attr("action");
    var mehtodtype = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

    // Clear fields data. (password).
    $('form :input[type=password]').attr('value','');

    // Remove selected pictures field.
    $('#Picture').attr('src', '../../img/User No-Frame.png');

    alert(postdata);

    $.ajax
    ({
        $.ajaxFileUpload
        ({
            fileElementId: 'file_browse'
        }),
        type: mehtodtype,
        url: path,
        data: postdata,


        success: function(data) 
        {
           alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

### html:

```
                                    <form class="wrefresh" action="../Code Files/User.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                            <div id="photo_settings2" style="margin-left:74px;">
                                                    <img id="Picture" src="../../img/User No-Frame.png"/>       
                                            </div>

                                            <br><br><br><br>

                                            <div id='Upload_Panel' style="margin-left: 32px;">
                                                    <input name='file' type='file' id='file_browse' onchange="readURL(this,'Picture')" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="delete" style="margin-top: -40px; margin-left: 198px; cursor: pointer">
                                                    <img src="../../img/Delete_Panel.png">
                                            </div>

                                            <div style="margin-left:144px; margin-top:-15px"></div>

....
</form>
```

### php code:

```
                    // Executes a statement.
                    $check = oci_execute($result);

                    $UploadDirectory = '/wamp/www/img/Users/Users/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory))
                    {
                        //die('Success! File Uploaded.');
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //die('error uploading File!');
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not send the file data directly to server using jquery or javascript, as javascript doesnt have the local file system access and for these purpose we put enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute. to use desired functionality you can use the plugin called form ajax submit http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: like this:            $('#file_browse').ajaxForm(function() { 
                fileElementId: 'file_browse'
            }); 
,
enctype:"multipart/form-data"
??

Comment: no $('#formId').ajaxForm(); so the plugin will pick the action of form and also enctype will be in form tag not in script.

Comment: in the braces you have to give form id not file element id.

Comment: ok i have the $('.wrefresh').ajaxForm(); { fileElementId = 'file_browse', } enctype:"multipart/form-data" is in my form. but still no luck.

Comment: what is in action attribute of form? and also the processing script of form which is in action attribute.. you will access posted file using $_FILES['file_browse'];

Comment: i am accseing it through files['file']['name']

Comment: use $_FILES['file_browse']['name'] mark capital letter _FILES  is special php array for uploaded files and first argument should be name of file field

Comment: $_FILES['file']['name'] this should be used because the name='file'. Not working ajax :/

Answer (score 0):

Solve by adding these two things.

1. contentType: false
2. processData: false

and changing this too:
`var postdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);`

```
 <script>

` var frm = $('.wrefresh');`

    frm.submit(function (ev)
    {

            ev.preventDefault();

            var postdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            var path = $(this).attr("action");
            var mehtodtype = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

            // Clear fields data. (password).
            $('form :input[type=password]').attr('value','');

            // Remove selected pictures field.
            $('#Picture').attr('src', '../../img/User No-Frame.png');

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: mehtodtype,
                url: path,
                data: postdata,

                contentType: false,
                processData: false,

                success: function(data) 
                {
                  alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```